# Crear variable con palabras cuando tenga más de un espacio

Tags: php

Tengo una frase con múltiples espacios en blanco, como por ejemplo:

```
"aaa                 bbb bb      ccc       ddd       fff"
```

y quiero obtener las palabras que tengan más de un espacio. En ese ejemplo, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` y `f` deberían ser variables que pueda usar.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Puedes compartir que es lo que has intentato hasta el momento? Un saludo :)

Comment: ¿Por qué las variables sería `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` y `f`? ¿No sería `aaa`, `bbb` (o `bbb-bb`), `ccc`, `ddd`y `fff`? Aparte, deberías incluir qué es lo que has intentado hasta el momento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilicé [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-split.php) para solucionar el problema:

```
$parts = preg_split('/ {2,}/', "esta     es    la    respuesta     que buscaba");
```

Que devuelve:

```
Array
(
    [0] => esta
    [1] => es
    [2] => la
    [3] => respuesta
    [4] => que buscaba
)
```

entonces ...

```
$a = $parts[0];
$b = $parts[1];
$c = $parts[2];
$d = $parts[3];
$f = $parts[4];
```

con el indice del arraglo ya se puede usar la palabra que necesito..

Comment: La expresión regular no es correcta. Si observas, no está separando `que` y `buscaba`. Para que separe cada palabra deberías ponerla así: **`$parts = preg_split('/\s+/', "esta     es    la    respuesta     que buscaba");`**

Comment: @A.Cedano, el titulo de la pregunta dice _"[..]cuando tenga más de un espacio"_ igual considero que el OP no ha dejado claro cual es el resultado esperado.

Comment: El resultado esperado esta en la respuesta